# python for firefox extensions?

Tags: python, firefox, plugins, firefox-addon

Can I use python in firefox extensions? Does it work?

Answer (score 25):

**Yes**, through an extension for mozilla, Python Extension (pythonext).

Originally hosted in [mozdev](http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/), PythonExt project have move to Google code, **you can see it in [PythonExt in Google code](http://code.google.com/p/pythonext/)**.

Comment: Note, this seems to be an inactive project. Last commit was 6 months ago, and it doesn't seem feature or fix related.

Comment: So my users would have to install this in addition to the extension I'm making?