# Can I create a firefox plugin using Python?

Tags: python, firefox-addon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python for firefox extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302567/python-for-firefox-extensions)

I want to create a plugin for Firefox that could simplify text. I have code to simplify text written in Python. So I need to know whether it is possible for me to build the Firefox plugin in Python?